# Rock, paper, scissors in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just working on a rock, paper, scissors game in React. I am trying to display the following information: player selection, computer selection, round winner and player points. The problem is that the game first displays the selection of players and only in the next round informs who won - at this time I have new player choices. How can I fix it?

Counter.js

```
import ResultInfo from "./ResultInfo";

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 10,
      ran: "",
      id: "stone",
      temp: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1),
      userPoint: 0,
      pcPoint: 0,
      roundLimit: 10,
      roundWinner: ""
    };

    this.choice = this.choice.bind(this);
    this.lottery = this.lottery.bind(this);
  }

  choice = event => {
    this.setState({
      id: event.target.id
    });
  };

  lottery = (id, temp) => {
    this.choice(id);
    this.setState(({ temp }) => ({
      temp: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1)
    }));

    if (this.state.temp === 1) {
      this.setState({
        ran: "paper"
      });
    } else if (this.state.temp === 2) {
      this.setState({
        ran: "stone"
      });
    } else if (this.state.temp === 3) {
      this.setState({
        ran: "scissors"
      });
    }
    console.log("pc:" + this.state.temp);
    console.log("user:" + this.state.id);
    if (
      (this.state.id === "paper" && this.state.ran === "stone") ||
      (this.state.id === "stone" && this.state.ran === "scissors") ||
      (this.state.id === "scissors" && this.state.ran === "paper")
    ) {
      this.setState(({ userPoint, roundWinner }) => ({
        userPoint: userPoint + 1,
        roundWinner: "User"
      }));
    } else if (this.state.id === this.state.ran) {
      this.setState(({ roundWinner }) => ({
        roundWinner: "Draw"
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(({ pcPoint, roundWinner }) => ({
        pcPoint: pcPoint + 1,
        roundWinner: "PC"
      }));
    }

    /*   if (this.state.ran === 1) {
      this.setState(({ count }) => ({
        count: count + 1
      }));
    }

    if (this.state.count === 5) {
      alert("game over");
      this.setState(({ count }) => ({
        count: 0
      }));
    }
    console.log(this.state.ran); */
  };
  render(props) {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.lottery} id="paper">
          paper
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.lottery} id="stone">
          stone
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.lottery} id="scissors">
          scissors
        </button>
        <ResultInfo
          id={this.state.id}
          ran={this.state.ran}
          roundWinner={this.state.roundWinner}
          userPoint={this.state.userPoint}
          pcPoint={this.state.pcPoint}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

ResultInfo.js

```
import { render } from "react-dom";

class ReactInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(props) {
    return (
      <>
        <div>You choice: {`${this.props.id}`}</div>
        <div>PC choice: {`${this.props.ran}`}</div>
        <div>Round Winner: {`${this.props.roundWinner}`}</div>
        <div>User Point: {`${this.props.userPoint}`}</div>
        <div>PC Point: {`${this.props.pcPoint}`}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default ReactInfo;
```

My React Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stone-paper-scissors-8xgni

Comment: @MattOestreich You  just need to add the counter component in app.js. He might have forgot to do that.

Comment: Well that's true but looks like a new user.

Comment: That's fair enough

Answer (score 0):

You are doing multiple state updates and relying on their updated values. However, `setSate()` is asynchronous. Let me know if you don't know what that means and I will go in a little more detail.

I refactored your code into making one state update:

```
  lottery = event => {
    const id = event.target.id;
    const temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
    let ran,
      roundWinner,
      userPoint = this.state.userPoint,
      pcPoint = this.state.pcPoint;

    if (temp === 1) ran = "paper";

    if (temp === 2) ran = "stone";

    if (temp === 3) ran = "scissors";

    if (
      (id === "paper" && ran === "stone") ||
      (id === "stone" && ran === "scissors") ||
      (id === "scissors" && ran === "paper")
    ) {
      userPoint += 1;
      roundWinner = "User";
    } else if (id === ran) {
      roundWinner = "Draw";
    } else {
      pcPoint += 1;
      roundWinner = "PC";
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      id,
      temp,
      userPoint,
      pcPoint,
      roundWinner,
      ran
    }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`SetState()` is not synchronous (and you can see it in console.log()'s which you have placed yourself). Do not use the pattern

```
this.SetState({ some_var: some_value })
do_something(this.state.some_var)
```

instead use `some_value` directly (it's also looks cleaner)

```
this.SetState({ some_var: some_value })
do_something(some_value)
```

I edited your Sandbox, the result is here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stone-paper-scissors-75qmx